# Issue while installing the weblogic 12 jar at windows

Tags: jar, installation, weblogic12c, oracle-home

```
C:\Program Files\weblogic>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java" -jar fmw_12.2.1.1.0_wls_quick.jar
Launcher log file is C:\Users\kb\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2016-10-05_10-23-23PM\launcher2016-10-05_10-23-23PM.log.
Extracting the installer . . . . . . . . Done
Checking if CPU speed is above 300 MHz.   Actual 2594    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 512 MB    Passed
Checking if this platform requires a 64-bit JVM.   Actual 64    Passed (64-bit not required)
Checking temp space: must be greater than 300 MB.   Actual 825693 MB    Passed


Preparing to launch the Oracle Universal Installer from C:\Users\kb\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2016-10-05_10-23-23PM
Log: C:\Users\kb\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2016-10-05_10-23-23PM\install2016-10-05_10-23-23PM.log

*****************************************************


Distribution Name : Oracle Fusion Middleware 12c WebLogic and Coherence Developer
Distribution Version : 12.2.1.1.0

Oracle Home : C:\Program Files\weblogic\wls12210
Java Home : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102

Note: Oracle Home not supplied (defaulted to <present working dir>\wls12210)

*****************************************************

Copyright (c) 1996, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Skipping Software Updates
Starting check : CertifiedVersions
Expected result: One of 6.1,6.2,6.3,10.0
Actual Result: 10.0
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Passed
CertifiedVersions Check: Success.


Starting check : CheckJDKVersion
Problem: This JDK version was not certified at the time it was made generally available. It may have been certified following general availability.

Recommendation: Check the Supported System Configurations Guide (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/downloads/fusion-certification-100350.html) for further details. Press "Next" if you wish to continue.

Expected result: 1.8.0_77
Actual result: 1.8.0_102
Warning: Check:CheckJDKVersion completed with warnings.


Validations are enabled for this session.
Verifying data
[VALIDATION] [ERROR]:INST-07004: Oracle Home location contains one or more invalid characters
[VALIDATION] [SUGGESTION]:The directory name may only contain alphanumeric, underscore (_), hyphen (-) , or dot (.) characters, and it must begin with an alphanumeric character. Provide a different directory name.
installation Failed. Exiting installation due to data validation failure.

The log(s) can be found here: C:\Users\kb\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2016-10-05_10-23-23PM.

Press Enter to exit
```

1. I tried SET ORACLE_HOME="C:\Program Files\weblogic"
2. executing from C:\Program Files\weblogic

How to solve this problem? Or is there any other weblogic jar files needs to be used?

Answer (score 18):

Set the ORACLE_HOME argument when executing the Java command at the command-line:
i.e.:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin>java -jar C:\WebLogicDownloads\fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls_quick.jar ORACLE_HOME=C:\WebLogicServer
```

Comment: Thanks, It was very helpful

Comment: ORACLE_HOME needs to point to a not existing folder. It will be created by the installer and files get extracted there. Example: c:\weblogic\wls14110

Answer (score 2):

The issue is solved. I changed the JDK location to C driver "C:\" from "C:\program files".

Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me also, changing the jdk location to directly under D drive solved the issue .thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the following error is important:

```
INST-07004: Oracle Home location contains one or more invalid characters
[VALIDATION] [SUGGESTION]:The directory name may only contain alphanumeric,
underscore (_), hyphen (-) , or dot (.) characters, and it must begin with 
an alphanumeric character. Provide a different directory name. installation
Failed. Exiting installation due to data validation failure.
```

The problem is the space in the middle of "Program Files". Do to the limitations on the name you can't even use the 8-character abbreviated name for `Program Files` (usually `PROGRA~1`). I suggest you install WebLogic directly into the root of your C: drive, so try using `C:\weblogic`.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your folder name with setup is invalid or you are installing from rar directly then this problem arises.  Check the software information path to see if it is invalid.

Comment: Hello! The question you have answered seems to already have similar solutions. Please consider looking at other answers before giving your own.