# getting error while installing weblogic server12.1 on windows 10

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, windows-10, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am getting the following error(given in the screenshot) while installing Oracle Weblogic 12.1 on Windows 10 . What should I do?
[image]

Comment: Try running the installer under compatibility mode.

Comment: could you post the error instead sharing link ?

Comment: Here you can find a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886707/issue-while-installing-the-weblogic-12-jar-at-windows just in case it can help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Check the current OS version, eg : 10.0.XX.X
```

Pick first 3 digits, i.e. 10.0, add line under  tag on refhost.xml file like

VERSION VALUE="10.0"

Go back and start your installation process.